# java.lang.ClassCastException error on Test server

Tags: java, classcastexception

I am trying to write a recursive function where i can have an array of any type, string, int , bigdecimal, any objects
So I am trying to write something like this :

```
if(foo.getClass().isArray())
{
    Object[] objects = (Object[]) foo; //FAILS here
    //do something
}
```

This passes in the code but it fails on server.
Getting the error

```
class [Z cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Object; ([Z and [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

SO, for example if there is an int[] then it comes inside the loop but when it tries to do (Object[])o, it fails here.

Comment: That's quite expected. But what is your question?

Comment: @JBNizet How should i resolve this ? WHat code would resolve this error ?

Comment: In Java you have primitive types (like int) and objects (like Number or Integer). You can form arrays from both, but while you can cast a Number[] to an Object[], there's no way to do this for an int[]

Comment: Well, don't try to cast an array of ints to an array of Objects. Test if it's an array of ints, and cast it to an array of ints. Or better, explain what yo're trying to achieve, because testing all possible types of an rgument isn't something you should generally do.

Comment: @JBNizet I am trying to use reflection and see if any of my objects contain a decimal value and i do some logic on that. SO the object contains array for string or BigDecimal or some other object itself. Thats why i cant possibly try all the types.

Comment: @sshah you can't possibly try "all the types", but you also can't meaningfully *use* all the types either: you might want to do specific things with a few types, but thereafter you are either going to treat everything as if it were an `Object[]`, or ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

1. you cannot assign an array of primitives, i.e. int[], into an array of Object[]
2. casting an array of objects to Object[] is unnecessary because all classes inherits from the Object class. For clarification on this last point see the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: 2. It's unnecessary if you know `foo` is a variable of type `Object[]`, but presumably you only know that `foo` is an `Object`, because otherwise you wouldn't need to check if it's an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you know something is an array, but may be a primitive array (like `int[]`), use the [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) class to access it.

For example:

```
Object firstElement = Array.get(foo, 0);
```

will retrieve the first element of the array.

Other helper methods exist to get the array elements as primitive types, e.g. [`Array.getInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#getInt-java.lang.Object-int-).

---

You can't concisely get an `Object[]` from your `Object`, but you can trivially turn it into a `List<Object>`, by implementing [`AbstractList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html):

```
List<Object> myReflectiveList = new AbstractList<Object>() {
  @Override public int size() { return Array.getLength(foo); }

  @Override public Object get(int index) {
    return Array.get(foo, index);
  }
};
```

Now you can treat this like any (unmodifiable) `List`.

---

You can *verbosely* get an `Object[]`, by explicitly testing each of the possible primitive types, and falling back to `Object[]`:

```
Object[] objs = new Object[Array.getLength(foo)];
if (foo.getClass().equals(int[].class)) {
  for (int i = 0; i < objs.length; ++i) {
    objs[i] = Array.getInt(foo, i);
  }
} else if (foo.getClass().equals(long[].class)) {
  // For loop, with Array.getLong
} /* etc for other primitive types */ else {
  // If it's an array but not a primitive array, you can just copy.
  System.arraycopy(foo, 0, objs, 0, objs.length);
}
```

Comment: I want to return something like Object[]

Comment: Will a `List<Object>` suffice? I've updated the answer to show how to do that.

Comment: Thanks Andy,  So no other way than explicitly testing for each type ?

Comment: @sshah you can probably do it with a `Map`, where the keys are classes and values are a function that gives you an element from an array of that type. But other than that, you'd have to check explicitly, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this via a simple overloading (as primitives and objects arrays copy are handled differently:

```
if (foo.getClass().isArray()) {
    Object[] objects = castToObjectArray(foo);
    // do something
}
```

where :

```
/*
 * Generic cast applicable to any "Object"
 */
private static <T> Object[] castToObjectArray(T[] foo) {
    return Arrays.stream(foo).toArray();
    // OR
    // return Arrays.copyOf(foo, foo.length, Object[].class);
}

/***** Define primitives version below *******/

private static Object[] castToObjectArray(int[] foo) {
    return Arrays.stream(foo).mapToObj(x -> (Object) x).toArray();
}

// You need to define an overloaded version for all the primitive types you may use - simple copy past & change the parameter type.
```

Cheers!

Comment: The foo is not a T[], it will be just an object. So, castToObjectArray(foo) expects the parameter in the method to be object not T[] foo.